# Entity Data Model silently quits

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, mysql-connector

Before I describe the problem, I want to let you know that I went over like 30 different answers on Stack Overflow that seems to be similar to my problem, but none of thee solution helped me solve this.

**The issue:**

The wizard while creating ADP.NET Entity Data Model quits after I click "Next" in the "Choose Your Data Connection" step without any error or notification, the window just closes and no file is generated. There is nothing in the output or error window as well.

I have a C# .NET 4.6.1 web form project with the following packages:

- Entity Framework 6.2.0
- MySql.Data 8.0.11
- MySql.Data Entities 6.8.3
- MySql.Data Entity 6.10.7
- MySql.Web 8.0.11

I clean and rebuild the project, load VS with Administer account, tried to remove connections from server explorer and try again, I have the latest .NET connector installed, but nothing helped.

Related Web.cofig parts:

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />  
</configSections>

...

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>

<DbProviderFactories>      
 <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```